# CakePHP and Translate Behavior

Tags: cakephp, internationalization, cakephp-2.0

I'am a French developer so sorry for my bad english.

I have a problem when inserting data in multiple languages ​​on my site.
I said that my i18n table was created from the console and inserted on a single language it works!

This is the error:

**Database Error**

Error: SQLSTATE [42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'
SQL Query: INSERT INTO `` ` expandingCakePHP. Accesses ``(`name`) VALUES (Array)
Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create app / View / Errors / pdo_error.ctp

My admin_add.ctp (file View / Accesses)

```
foreach (Configure :: read ('Config.languages​​') as $lang) {
echo $this-> Form-> input ('Access.name.'. $lang, array ('label' => __ ('Name'). '(. $lang.') '));
}
```

My access.php (Model File)

```
var $actsAs = array (
   'Translate' => array (
      'name' => '_name'
   )
);
```

My AccessesController.php (Controller folder)

```
admin_add public function () {
   if ($this-> request-> is ('post')) {
      $this-> Access-> create ();
      $this-> Access-> locale = Configure :: read ('Config.languages​​');
      if ($this-> Access-> save ($ this-> request-> data)) {
         $this-> Session-> setFlash (__ ('The access has been saved'), 'notif');
         $this-> redirect (array ('action' => 'index'));
      }
      else {
         $this-> Session-> setFlash (__ ('The Access Could not be saved. Please, try again.'), 'notif', array ('type' => 'alert-error'));
      }
   }
}
```

In my bootstrap.php (Config file)

```
Configure :: write ('Config.languages​​', array ('eng', 'eng'));
Configure :: write ('Config.language', 'eng');
Configure :: write ('App.encoding', 'utf-8');
```

The structure received by the post form is correct?
/ app / Controller / AccessesController.php (line 46)

```
array (
   'Access' => array (
      'name' => array (
         'eng' => 'title',
         'eng' => 'title'
      )
   )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
 $this->Model->save($this->request->data,false);
```

Answer (score 0):

The post structure seems wrong, e.g. see http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveassociated-array-data-null-array-options-array

It should be more like:

```
array (
   'Access' => array (
      'name' => 'a name',
      'title' => 'a title',
      'another model' => array(...)
      )
   )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use `$this->Model->saveAll($this->request->data);`

instead of `$this->Model->save($this->request->data);`